# Clopen Sets and Sets being Neither Open Nor Closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, real-numbers

I am very new to Topology. I do not have a college math degree, only highschool math. I have a real hard time understanding how a set can be both open and closed. And set being neither open nor closed.

Is it correct to think of a set being both open and closed as below?

Let's consider a topology over two sets (A and B) that are disjoint. For example, A = (1,2) and B = (4,5). Both the sets are open as they don't contain their limit points. However, by definition, a set is closed if that set's compliment is open. Therefore, A is closed because A's compliment (which is B) is open and B is closed because its compliment is open.

I am yet to come up with an example for sets that are neither open nor closed. It would be really great if someone can give a simple example for that.

Comment: The rationals are neither open nor closed. Their interior is empty, their closure is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The empty set and the entire set are both open and closed.  And in this context, compl*e*ment does not have an *i*

Comment: Compliment: “Your post is well crafted and you provide appropriate context and evidence of work. Well done!”.  *Complement*: the stuff that is not part of that being considered.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. I was misreading the question.

Comment: When you talk about sets being open, closed, or neither, it's important to be clear about which topology you mean.  To take your example, $A$ is clopen in the subspace topology induced by the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ on the subspace (of $\Bbb R$) $A \cup B$, but $A$ is merely open (not also closed) considered as a subspace of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I can't resist to recommend this "source of inspiration" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Answer (score 1):

In the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, any half-open interval of the form $[a,b)$ or $(a,b]$ where $a<b$ is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an open set in the real line is a set that is equal to the set of its inner points, that is: a set $A$ is open if for every $a\in A$ there exist a small number $\varepsilon$ such that $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ is contained in $A$, a set is closed if its complement is open. Take $A=[0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$, this set is not open since $(0-\varepsilon,0+\varepsilon)$ will never be contained in $A$ but $0\in A$. And it's complement is not open since $1\in A^c$ but $(1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ cant be contained in $A^c$, so $[0,1)$ is neither open or closed.